# How to get column data of a row based on row index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table with an id dynamictable. If i select a row i'm able to get row index. How to get all column values by passing row index.
I'm trying to delete a row... please help me.

My code is like this

```
$('#dynamictable').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
 var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
 var firstvalue = $('#dynamictable tbody').children(rowindex).children('td').eq(1).text();

});
```

Comment: `I'm trying to delete a row` so why do you need to get text content then?

Comment: to delete contents present in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `2` with your required row index

To get all column value in a row use

```
$('table tr:eq(2) td').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

To delete a row use `remove()`

```
$('table tr:eq(2)').remove();
```

Comment: thanks.. can u tell me how to get value if column data is a combobox value

Comment: give a class name `combobox` to combobox and then `$(this).find('.combobox').val()`

Comment: and one more     <td class='hidden'><div divNumber=1><input type='hidden' name='xyz' id='xyz'  value =''></input></div></td> . how to get vale of this hidden column

Comment: simply u ca n get by using it's id `$('#xyz').val()`

Comment: yup its so simple :-)  i missed # in tat,so it was not coming,m new to jquery.. thanks for helping me ...

Answer (score 0):

To get column values use

```
$('#dynamictable').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
   var column1 = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html(); // gets column 1 values
   var column2 = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html(); // gets column 2 values

});
```

To delete a row clicked

```
$('#dynamictable').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
     $(this).remove();

});
```